# Hello Views/Form Stuff/Custon Button tutorial error

Tags: android

Flush with success on getting "hello Android" to run, I'm working on the tutorial at [link text](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-formstuff.html#CustomButton) using Eclipse. When I create the android_button.xml file in res/drawable/, I get errors for each of the  in

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/android_pressed"
          android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/android_focused"
          android:state_focused="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/android_normal" />
</selector>
```

The errors (repeated for each item) are:

```
Description Resource    Location    Type    Path
error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/android_focused'). android_button.xml  line 5  Android AAPT Problem    /HelloFormStuff/res/drawable
error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/android_focused'). android_button.xml  line 5  Android AAPT Problem    /HelloFormStuff/res/drawable
```

I'm afraid I don't know which resource should match the names or if I have overlooked something or misnamed something. Help resolving this is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably missed this line in the instructions:

**Copy the images on the right into the res/drawable/ directory of your project. These will be used for the different button states.**

Just copy those little android icons into the directory and it should work

Comment: Yes - Somehow I missed that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

On the [link](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-formstuff.html#CustomButton) you gave there are three android icons near
**android_button.xml** code. Just right click them and "save as"

Save them in your res/drawable directory along with android_button.xml.

note that I assume you are creating that xml file in res/drawable directory
and note in drawable-XXXX directory created by eclipse. You will have to manually
create a new folder drawable in res directory, since its not default eclipse stuff.

Comment: Yes - thanks! On my last try, I selected the API for 1.5 and it only created the single res/drawable directory.